# New react project: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

Tags: reactjs

I just started a project with the `npx create-react-app` command
Also I'm using Docker to run the project
I have only modified the App.js file in src folder:

```
   import './App.css';
    
    const  App = () => {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Hello, R ! </h1>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

I have the error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /app/src/App.js: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level. (25:0)

  23 | }
  24 |
> 25 | export default App;
     | ^
  26 |
    at instantiate (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:72:32)
    at constructor (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:367:12)
    at FlowParserMixin.raise (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3678:19)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatementContent (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:14883:18)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatement (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:14782:17)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatement (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:5952:24)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:15441:25)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseBlockBody (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:15432:10)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseBlock (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:15416:10)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseFunctionBody (/app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:14090:24)
```

Maybe it's an indentation or missing bracket problem, but I can't find it

Comment: Pretty sure there's more to it for Docker but I've not done it. I found this article though. https://collabnix.com/creating-your-first-react-app-using-docker/

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I was looking at the wrong place.
I used the command *docker-compose up* insteed of **docker-compose up --build -d** :')

Apparently I need to recreate an image at every modification, I thought it was only needed when you modifying your Docker's files, i guess I still don't have completely understand Docker